# What is this 2-3cm insect found in South-Eastern Brazil?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: Flat matt black beetle? with green marks on either 'wing' case]

Noted in South-Eastern Brazil rainforest at low level - about 2-3 cm from head to tail.

Maybe a Cassadine Beetle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Maybe a cassadine beetle ?

You are correct! This insect does belong to the subfamily [Cassidinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassidinae) (common referred to as "tortoise beetles"), and is of the species *Stolas aenea*.

[image]